# Authentication, bussiness logic and several entities in asp.net core

Tags: design, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm working on an asp.net core application, using Identity as authentication/authorization management. Depending on the role the user can do "some thing", this is the normal way of authorization. But when the user is an entity related to other entity the business logic get ambiguous. This is a pseudo code example:

```
    class User: IdentityUser{Roles {}}
    class Roles {"Bartender", "Admin"}
    class Bartender: User {}
    class Bar{ Bartender Worker {get;set;}}
```

The business logic say that in a bar can only work the Bartender associated as Worker, so the user authenticated must fulfill this restriction.
The problem is that the User must have the role "Bartender" and be a Bartender, two requirements not only one.
We can work with this double restriction but if there are a better or an alternative solution I want to know.

Comment: What are looking to get answered? There isn't much of a question there.

Comment: Using types to enforce security rules is a terrible idea. Why do you have a Bartender in the first place? What make it different from a regular User?

Comment: The entity Bartender is not use for security, is just an entity en the model. As can be Manager or Waitress in the business modeled. But is a Role to. You suggest not to model the business as entities and only have User and manage all business rules with Roles